# $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/') doesn't work when the path starts with '.'

Tags: angularjs, nginx, gulp, angular-ui-router, browser-sync

I have the following in my Angular app (v1.5.3, ui-router v0.3.2):

> /app/router.js
>
> ```
> function router ($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
>   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
>   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
> }
>
> angular
>   .module('analytics')
>   .config(router);
> ```

Generally this works as expected. I have no route for `/nonsense`, so requests to `/nonsense` are routed to `/`. However, if I try to navigate to `/.nonsense`, I get a 40x response (404 in Chrome and with `curl`; 403 with Firefox and Safari; didn't test IE or Edge).

But requests to `/#/.nonsense` are correctly re-routed to `/`.

So preliminary question: **is this the expected/desired behavior?**

And primary question: **if it's not the behavior I expect/desire, what workarounds might I try?**

### UPDATE #1

It's been suggested that this is not an Angular issue, but a server configuration issue.

I am running the app locally using gulp (v4.0.0) + browser-sync (v2.12.5). In prod, we're using nginx. The issue is consistent in both environments.

The browser-sync config code is:

> /gulp-config/serve.js
>
> ```
> const browserSyncInit = (baseDir, routes) => {
>   sync.init({
>     startPath: '/',
>     server: {
>       baseDir: baseDir,
>       routes: routes
>     },
>     browser: 'default',
>     notify: false,
>     // The variable C is a config object defined elsewhere 
>     host: C.siteConfig.webHost,
>     port: C.siteConfig.webPort,
>     https: C.siteConfig.webProtocol === 'https',
>     open: 'external'
>   });
> }
> ...
> browserSyncInit(
>   [C.tmp(), C.app()],
>   {'/bower_components': 'bower_components'}
> );
> ```

So if it is indeed a server config issue, I would probably be able to amend the routes object being passed in, i.e.:

`routes['/**/.*'] = ''` **UPDATE #2: this didn't actually work :(**

But I'm not sure how to accomplish this type of thing in nginx as I'm not involved in the deployment of the project and have never worked with nginx.

**I assume there is a config process in nginx for intercepting routes by using wildcard characters or regex?**

### UPDATE #3

This is the nginx config for the Angular app portion of the site.

> /etc/nginx/slave/sites-available/example-dev_proxy.conf
>
> ```
> upstream example-dev {
>   zone upstream_dynamic 128k;
>   server example-dev.service.internal.consul:31238 resolve;
> }
>
> server {
>   listen 443 ssl;
>   server_name *.dev.example.com;
>   server_tokens off;
>   add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
>   add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
>   ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/slave/ssl/dhparam.pem;
>
>   location / {   
>     proxy_pass https://example-dev;
>     proxy_redirect off;
>     proxy_set_header Host ;
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For ;
>     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP ;
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto ;
>   }
>
>   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/slave/ssl/example_dev_proxy.crt;
>   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/slave/ssl/example_dev_proxy.key;
>   ssl_verify_client off;
>   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
>   ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
>   ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
>   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
> }
> ```

Comment: this isn't happening in angular, this is happening on your server;  in some servers, `/.` is treated differently.  you should show your server config, and also consider adding a tag for the server you are using.

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't the HTTP response be the same in each browser? It seems like there is no clear response from the server and that's why browsers are handling the response differently.

Comment: Show nginx config

Comment: Added nginx config in update #3 section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like this was an nginx issue, not an Angular issue. The default behavior is to return a 403 for any path that starts with a dot. But as I understand it, this a way to override the default behavior to return a 404 instead:

```
location ~ /\. { deny all }
```

More info on this [here](https://programming-review.com/nginx-disable-access-to-htaccess-file/). And for nginx n00bs like myself, I found [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#matching-location-blocks) helpful in understanding the above line.